# java string comparsion by words ignoring space

Tags: java, string

How to compare dynamic strings by considering the words in java  ?

For example:

```
narendar baddam
```

and

```
narendar        baddam
```

should ignore the extraspace for dynamic input.

need to be same

Comment: Remove the spaces and compare?

Comment: Take the string, replace the blanks with nothing and compare the modified strings.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the replace mechanism is good enough for comparing strings without considering white spaces. You can use following (using regex):

// regular expression \s for white space tab etc

System.out.println(**a.replaceAll("\s", "").equals(b.replaceAll("\s", ""))**);

This will take care of all white space (including tabs) at leading, trailing and in-between of string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace function (" " to "") together with the equals.
1 minute of searching the web would have brought you there.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
String a = "narendar baddam";
String b = "narendar        baddam";

a.replaceAll(" ", "").equals(b.replaceAll(" ", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good but don't cover all whitespace. A better approach would be to delete all non-alphabetic and replace it with a single space:

```
a.replaceAll("\\W+", "").trim().equals(b.replaceAll("\\W+", "").trim())
```

This replaces all occurrences of 1 or more non-word characters with a single space.

You should probably also do a trim() to remove leading and trialing spaces.

Comment: OP might care about the difference between "$5" and "€5".

Comment: @Michelle true, however modifying the regex would allow those characters to be exclouded. They probably don't care about the difference between "foo, bar" and "foo bar" though.